# Are there any known interesting F-(co)algebras where F isn't a set endofunctor?

Tags: category-theory, coalgebras

Are there any known interesting F-(co)algebras where F isn't a $Set$ endofunctor? Every example I can think of deals with sets: an algebra of $X\mapsto 1+X$ for natural numbers, an algebra of $X\mapsto 1+A\times X$ for lists, a coalgebra of $X\mapsto A\times X$ for streams, etc. I'm not alone in this, Adámek writes

> Although all important examples of application of coalgebra seem to concern
>   coalgebras in Set, there are good reasons to develop the whole theory in an abstract category, e.g., [...]

in his "[Introduction to coalgebra](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/TAC/volumes/14/8/14-08.pdf)".

Surely there are interesting cases dealing with domains? Are there any dealing with the categories of topological spaces, of algebras, etc?

Comment: Well, coalgebras! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra)

Comment: No, for natural numbers you want the _algebra_ for the endofunctor $X \mapsto 1 + X$. Similarly, lists are an _algebra_ for the functor $X \mapsto A \times X$. The _coalgebras_ for $X \mapsto A \times X$ are streams.

Comment: @ZhenLin : You're right; I've corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mariano mentions in the comments, [coalgebras over a field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra) are in particular coalgeras over the functor $X \mapsto X \otimes X$ on vector spaces, although there is additional structure and properties here. For examples see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130643/is-it-true-that-nature-promotes-products) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76509/what-is-a-coalgebra-intuitively).

Leinster's *[A general theory of self-similarity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4474)* addresses the question of characterizing topological spaces as terminal coalgebras in interesting ways. Examples include $[0, 1]$, the Cantor set, and, conjecturally, all Julia sets.

If $P$ is a poset regarded as a category in the usual way and $F : P \to P$ is an endomorphism of $P$, then algebras over $F$ are elements $x \in P$ such that $F(x) \le x$, and similarly coalgebras over $F$ are elements $x \in P$ such that $x \le F(x)$. Initial algebras are then least fixed points, and terminal coalgebras are greatest fixed points; see, for example, the [Knaster-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).

A rich class of examples are given by [coalgebras over comonads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)), which can be built out of [any adjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Monads_and_adjunctions) and which are therefore extremely general.